# Change Visual State Pressed Button Background UWP

Tags: c#, button, uwp

I know how to do this in XAML, but I want to change the colors in a ContentDialog.

I can change the background and forground color, but I would also like to change the button colors when in a specific state ("Pressed", "PointOver", ...).

```
var contentDialog = new ContentDialog
{
    Content = "Test",
    Title = "Test",
    PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
};
var buttonStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Colors.Yellow));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.ForegroundProperty, Colors.White));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.IsPressedProperty, Colors.Green));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(VisualState...))
contentDialog.PrimaryButtonStyle = buttonStyle;
await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
```

How can I do this in code?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `ButtonBackgroundPressed` theme resource:

```
contentDialog.Resources["ButtonBackgroundPressed"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Or define a completely custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
const string Xaml = "<ControlTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" TargetType=\"Button\">" +
    "...</ControlTemplate>";

var buttonStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.TemplateProperty, XamlReader.Load(Xaml) as ControlTemplate));
contentDialog.PrimaryButtonStyle = buttonStyle;
```